# Why has nextChunk of ChunkedInput to return a new ChannelBuffer?

Tags: netty

I was doing a custom implementation of ChunkedInput in combination with the already provided ChunkedWriteHandler. For performance reasons i created a single ChannelBuffer within ChunkedInput and updated it upon each call of nextChunk and returned always the same updated ChannelBuffer. I found out that this approach obviously causes bytes not to be transmitted. The solution is to return always a new ChannelBuffer upon each call.

Why do i have to return always a new ChannelBuffer? This creates quite an overhead for memory allocation, object creation and garbage collection for large Streams. Is this Buffer queued for async processing?

Anyway i think it should be added to the API-Documentation that nextChunk HAS TO return a NEW ChannelBuffer everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats exactly the "problem" the ChannelBuffer is put in a queue to get written. So if you reuse it you may corrupt the content of it before it was written back.